# Improving FullCalendar render performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using the ui-calendar angular directive for FullCalendar and my month views are getting really slow. A calendar with ~100 events in the month view is taking 6s to render on my desktop and 20+ seconds on ipad (my primary delivery target).

The time seems to be all in rendering, i.e. i set the events array of my event source as single set of events (rather than adding them one at a time) and log that array to the console, which both happen instantaneously, but he view does not update for the above mentioned times.

Am i simply hitting the limits of what FullCalendar can handle in terms of events for a single view, could this be an artifact of the angular directive's application of ngModel (although i'm setting .events` on an existing source in that model directly) or are the other ways to tune or provide event sources that are more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in how `ngModel` hooks into FullCalendar. After manually initializing FullCalendar in a controller and using a function for events, the same data as before now loads in milliseconds on the desktop and about a second on the ipad.

Will need to dig into how the `ui-calendar` directive uses FullCalendar and see if it can be changed to get the same speed i get with just using FullCalendar directly

Comment: Arne we are hitting the same issue with the Angular directive we are using.  Did you make any headway on a solution to this issue?  When we try to show a calendar with 300 events it crashes most browsers.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, we ended up just bypassing angular to fix our problem.

Comment: I did the same thing and haven't had the bandwidth to go back and look at the underlying problem the model binding caused

Comment: I hear that.  We are in the same boat :)

Comment: Would anyone be able to shed some light on how you bypassed Angular to get FullCalendar working?

Comment: I instantiated it the normal javascript way inside of my controller and then manipulated that instance via calls inside the controller. I.e. the controller just holds a reference to fullcalendar and you treat it like a regular javascript object